# How to override endpoint in AWS-SDK-CPP to connect to minio server at localhost:9000

Tags: minio, aws-sdk-cpp

I tried something like:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
config.endpointOverride = Aws::String("localhost:9000");
```

It does not work.

It seems that AWS-SDK-CPP by default uses virtual hosting:

```
https://bucket-name/s3.amazonaws.com
```

However, to access Minio, we need path style access:

```
https://localhost:9000/minio/bucket-name
```

In AWS-SDK-JAVA, there is:

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder.withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
```

is there something similar in AWS-SDK-CPP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The switch between path style and virtual hosting is in S3Client constructor:

```
S3Client(const Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration& clientConfiguration = Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration(), bool signPayloads = false, bool useVirtualAdressing = true);
```

turn it off, as in:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
config.endpointOverride = Aws::String("172.31.30.127:9000");
config.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTP;
auto client = Aws::MakeShared<S3Client>("sample_s3_client", config, false, false);
```